# Things that Lightning Readiness Report Doesn't Cover?

Tags: lightning-experience

I ran a Lightning Readiness check against my Salesforce org and it gave me fair amount of information regarding things which are in classic not supported in LEX or needs to be migrated from Classic to LEX.

What I wanted to understand , Does Lightning Readiness report provides all information ? As I am in process of doing Lightning Migrations, I have read fair amount of details from sources available online.

But I want to learn from experiences with the Devs active on SFSE, is there anything I need to take care which Lightning Readiness report doesn't provide details of.

Basically ,

> I wanted to find out Lightning features which are not part of
>   readiness report but is available in classic org and which won't work
>   in LEX

E.g [What Does the Lightning Experience Readiness Check Evaluate?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_readiness_check_whats_checked.htm) I was checking details on this link and I observed following things it doesn't cover.
1. Email templates with attachments 
2. Applications

> The Readiness Check requires metadata to evaluate features. Therefore,
>   the report sometimes only evaluates a feature for a specific area. For
>   example, it covers Sales Cloud related lists, but not all lists in
>   general. **It covers email templates but not mass email**. There are some
>   features that the tool doesn’t evaluate at all, including **customizable
>   navigation, Ideas, macros, custom keyboard shortcuts, Recycle Bin,
>   reports, and dashboards**. We recommend that you manually evaluate the
>   features and customizations that aren’t covered by the Readiness
>   Check.

Another Article I am checking is [Compare Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_aloha_comparison.htm&type=5)